# what port does "ember-cli serve" use to serve mocks?

Tags: ember-cli

I am porting an ember application to ember-cli, and wanted to use the mock server facility.

What url are the mocks served at (by default, at least)?

I thought I'd look at the generated objects, but their location doesn't seem obvious. localhost:4200 seems to be serving only the client itself. Could it be under a prefix? Also where is the code that sets this up? -- "in the wild" I use oauth tokens, and may want to put auth and cors handling into the mocks to test this.

Comment: Digging, I find: node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/server/express-server.js includes server directly. The mock registers under /api/<resource> in fact "ember serve" reports "GET /api/users/1 200 5.629 ms - 1380". However, in the client trying to get from store hits /users/1 (without "api" prefix); going to "/api/users/1" directly in browser gives error: "Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/api/users/1' did not match any routes in your application". Curl 127.0.0.1:4200/api/users yields "cannot GET"; in this case, ember serve reports 404. I have some misconfiguration... but how to correct?

Comment: Added an application adapter to set the namespace to /api... now ajax points to /api/users/1 -- which I think should be served by server. However it isn't... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... the answer is: even if you are using ember-cli-coffeescript, you can't write server/ (or config/) code in coffee. Inside of generated server/server.js we have

```
var mocks      = globSync('./mocks/**/*.js', { cwd: __dirname }).map(require);
var proxies    = globSync('./proxies/**/*.js', { cwd: __dirname }).map(require);
```

I had converted my mocks to .litcoffee, which works in app/ and tests/, but not here.

I guess if I want to use coffeescript here, I need to compile in the Brocfile (or add to the addon...).